# php mysql not checking username and password on users table

Tags: php, html, mysql, verify

The Sign in page does not seem to be working like it should. It wont verify the *username* and *password* on the Users table so it will not allow for log in.

**PHP**

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     $userName=$_POST['userName'];
     $passWord=$_POST['passWord'];
     $result=mysqli_query($con,"select *from Users where `userName` ='$userName' and `passWord` ='$passWord'");
     if($result)
     {
          //echo "Successfully deleted".$id;
          $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);       
          //echo $count;
     }
     if($count==1)
     {
          $_SESSION['username']=$username;
          $_SESSION['passWord']=$passWord;
          header("location:users.php");
     }
     else
     {      
          header("location:index.php");  
     }
 }
 ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Sign in</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="signin">
    [ <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a> ]
    [ <a href="signin.php">Sign In</a> ]
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="concerts.php" target="_self">Concert</a></li>
      <li><a href="restaurants.php" target="_self">Restaurant</a></li>
      <li><a href="sports.php" target="_self">Sports</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <form name="signin" method="post" action="signin.php" id="form">
    Member Login <br /><br />
    Username<input name="userName" type="text"><Br />
    Password</td><input name="passWord" type="password"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is not getting the id_cust from the users table to store in the $id 
It is getting the right username from the signin page

```
<?php 
$result=mysqli_query($con, "select * from Users where `userName` ='$userName'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['id_cust'];
```

http://pastebin.com/RmBz1yL0

Comment: Can't guarantee if this is the problem or not, but the `*` and `from` in your SQL string are not separated with a space ("`select *from Users`")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to below.

```
 if($result)
        {
            //echo "Successfully deleted".$id;
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);       
            //echo $count;

            if($count==1)
            {
                   $_SESSION['userName']= $userName;
                   $_SESSION['passWord'] = $passWord;
                  header("location:users.php");
           }
           else
           {      
                  header("location:index.php");  
           }

        }
```

Comment: I changed the $_SESSION['passWord'] = $passWord

Comment: @swimmerbhs You need to put the $count==1 check inside the main if($result) code block. See my answer.

Comment: It will log on but I still dont know if it is workin the right way. http://pastebin.com/BuN1huNC from the sign in page i want to pass in the user name they entered and then read that row of the sports table where their id equals the one that is on that line. but it seems to not be passed in

Comment: @swimmerbhs Check the variable names in the session. Are you using userName or username? Do a print_r($_SESSION); to see what variables are actually stored and then call them by their correct name.

Comment: it is getting the name and password correctly. but not displaying the table http://notnormalmotorsports.com/NiteKrawler/index.php if you go to the sign in page it is Lauren justin02 is one of the log ins, it has all the baseball in it that you see on the main page

Answer (score 1):

```
select *from Users where `userName` ='$userName' and `passWord` ='$passWord'
```

replace with

```
select * from Users where `userName` ='$userName' and `passWord` ='$passWord'
```

Comment: The missing space between `*` and `FROM` should theoretically not be a a problem. At least the versions of mysql that I know don't require it.